# Stop loading external files if they're unresponsive

Tags: javascript

My web app loads an external JS file that sometimes hangs for 30+ seconds, making my page hang in turn.

I know I can take it out of the `head`, or load the file from my own server, or switch services. However, I was wondering if there's a way to stop loading external files if they're unresponsive for some amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Loading JavaScript files asynchronous can be a tricky thing if you have dependencies between the files. I'd prefer placing the `<script>`-tag in the bottom of the `<body>`. This way you can put dependencies underneath it, and in the dependencies you check for a variable only availably in your slow JS-file before executing functions dependant on the slow JS-file.  You also write that you could place the JS on your own server, so I guess it's on an external domain. If this is the case you can't use an ordinary XMLHttpRequest/AJAX call to load the JS-file asynchronously anyway.

If you absolutely want to load the file asynchronously and are ready to deal with the issues this might give you, then take a look at http://headjs.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to link external file in regular way and specify custom timeout for its loading.

You can try to make ajax request to file address and in the same time set timeout for 30 seconds. If request stills running you can cancel it. Otherwise inside html page you may create script tag with loaded content.

Comment: Cool, I'll try the ajax approach